# ubuntu fails to resolve DNS

Tags: networking, dns

Recently I started to experience strange behavior of my computer -- my browser sometimes suddenly fails to load pages. I restarted my `wlan0`
(`ip link set dev wlan0 up/down`) and reconnected to wifi but this did not solve the problem. Then I tried to `ping 8.8.8.8` and it worked! So it seems to me that DNS stopped working (judging by this picture, `192.30.253.112` is an ip of github.com)

[image]

Does anybody know what is happening and how can I solve it? For now I just reboot my PC and it starts working again.

PS while my browser does not work, skype and telegram work fine. Even browser on my phone works fine.

PPS my kernel version is 4.4.0-66-generic, my ubuntu version is 16.04

Comment: i suggest to edit file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf , section dns=systemd-resolved , the check the services systemd-resolved and resolvconf both are work as well

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple workaround for this problem.

`echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf`

This command solves problem when it appears but I still doesn't know what causes it.

Comment: `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` Change this file. Otherwise, it won't be there after the restart. https://www.dedunu.info/2020/05/24/ubuntu-20-04-server-change-dns-and-domain

Comment: @dedunumax the link is broken.

Comment: This is the new link. Sorry for that. https://tech.dedunu.info/2020/05/24/ubuntu-20-04-server-change-dns-and-domain/

Answer (score 0):

If ANY DNS lookup resolves then DNS is probably ok.

In your example you can ping 192.30.253.112 which is in the github network but that does not mean that this is the server that your DNS will resolve to.

In my case:

dig github.com returns 192.30.253.113

To isolate your issue, when your browser is unable to load a page, type:

nslookup desired_url

If you can't ping the IP that nslookup returns, the server is probably down (or you are being blocked).

If you can ping the IP but the page never loads you are probably being blocked or the site is having some sort of problem.  There are a variety of reasons why a site may block you.

If other Internet apps like Skype work but your browser doesn't, I'd be looking at your browser configuration or addons that might be causing problems.

Comment: Actually ALL sites are blocked for me (while from our PCs I can reach them) and also it's not just 1 browser -- all of which I have (Chrome, Mozila, Opera) don't work.

Comment: Also `dig github.com` returns me both 112 and 113

Comment: I'm happy to chat with you about this via PM.  My answer showed how to verify that DNS is working.  It's rather clear, based on your response, that you do not have a DNS problem.  If you can resolve the domain name with dig and if you can ping the IP it resolves to something in the browser(s) or the target web site is preventing a connection.  You can eliminate GUI browsers and all of those plugins by trying:   lynx github.com from a shell.

Comment: Well, I've already restarted my PC (to write this post e.g.) so I made this `dig` after rebooting (and thus everything worked fine). I just made it to verify that I used correct IP for github.